# Получить index элемента из набора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получить index элемента из набора

```js
$('.dop').on('click',function(){
var in = $(this).closest('[class^="col-"]').index();
$('#in').text(in);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div id="wb1">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div id="wb2">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div id="wb3">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div id="wb4">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div id="wb5">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="wb6">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="in"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, непонятно зачем получать `.row`, чтобы потом в ней искать `[class^="col-"]`. Можно сразу `$(this).closest('[class^="col-"]')`. Во-вторых, зачем вообще это делать, если в каждой колонке под одному элементу с классом "dop", а значит индекс кликнутой картинки будет совпадать с индексом объемлющей колонки. В-третьих, если это классы бутстрап, то вы сломали сетку, общая ширина колонок не может быть больше 12. В-четвёртых:

```js
var div = $('#in');
var items = $('.dop');
items.on('click', function() {
  div.text(items.index(this) + 1);
});
```

```css
.dop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div id="wb1">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div id="wb2">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div id="wb3">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div id="wb4">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div id="wb5">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="wb6">
      <img src="" class="dop">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="in"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, по первому вопросу-полагал,что closest ищет только ближайший элемент, а не селектор, вот и использовал find;
по второму-индекс нужен для дальнейшего манипулирования DOM;
в третих-это flex, но не суть, как я мог сломать если у меня их 6?

Comment: @spoon100500 [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: без each не получить индекс по this?

Comment: @spoon100500 можно. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: сделал так `$(this).closest('[class^="col-"]').index()`

Comment: @spoon100500 зачем?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92414/discussion-between-spoon-100500-and-sergey-gornostaev).